# DUVIDA posso fazer mais de uma requisição ajax na mesma pagina?

Tags: php, ajax

Estou fazendo uma busca no banco de dados e retornando esses dados em uma tabela via ajax, ai nesta mesma tabela existe uma coluna que possui um link que retorna mais informações sobre os dados, tudo isso por ajax. A primeira requisição ajax acontece conforme o esperado, porém a segunda requisão os dados aparecem e somem da tela rapidamente, eu notei isso pq coloquei um alert no ajax.responseText. A minha duvida é se posso executar duas requisições ajax na mesma pagina. Meu codigo js é esse aki.

```
function mostrar_fase()
    {
    ajax = xmlhttp();
    id_fase = document.getElementById('id_fase').value; 

    if(ajax)
    {               
        ajax.open("GET",'http://localhost/sac/Ajax/mostrar_fase/' + id_fase, true);     
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {       
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)             
            {                       
                document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;              

            }
        }
         ajax.send();
    }
}
```

A impressão que tenho é que devo zerar alguma variavel na primeira requisição ajax. Mais não sei oq seria. Esse codigo que postei é da segunda requisição, porém a primeira é muito semelhante a essa apenas muda uma variavel e o link.
Agradeço desde ja.

Comment: Podes usar quantas chamadas ajax quiseres. O que tens de defenir é para onde vai o conteúdo, o que envias para o servidor (e como isso condiciona a resposta) e como mostrar o conteúdo. Neste momento estás a sobreescrever o elemento `#resposta` é isso que queres? e não precisas de enviar dados respetivos à chamada específica?

Comment: #resposta representa uma div que tenho em menu codigo html e quero reescrever, os dados que preciso são consultados no bando de dados pela pagina que esta no ajax.open, e os dados da consulta são retornando da forma que necessito, pois coloco um alert no meu codigo para verificar isso. O problema é que os dados aparecem e logo somem da tela.

Comment: Como estás a chamar essa função `mostrar_fase()`?

Comment: esta dentro de uma coluna da tabela, desta forma <td><a href="" onclick="return mostrar_fase()" class="tiny button">Mostrar mais</a></td>

Comment: Se olhares no developer tools quantas vezes o ajax é chamado? corresponde às vezes que queres? fica dificil adivinhar sem ter um exemplo do problema... dá para fazer um jsFiddle com o problema? ou pelo menos com o teu código?

Answer (score 2):

**Sim é possível**, eu pessoalmente recomendo a utilização de jQuery pois torna-se mais fácil criar requisições via Ajax.

---

Eu desenvolvi um pequeno código que demonstra duas requisições ajax para a mesma página.

**HTML & JS:**

```
<html>

    <body>

        <button id="calc1">1+2</button>
        <button id="calc2">1+3</button>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#calc1").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: { x:"1", y:"2"},
                    success: function (data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                })
            });

            $("#calc2").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: { x:"1", y:"3"},
                    success: function (data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                })
            });

        </script>   
    </body> 
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];

echo $x+$y;
```

Poderás utilizar o código e testa-lo e verificarás que ambos os requisitos são executados sem quaisquer problemas, cabe depois a ti adaptar o código.